Unable to build in iOS when using `cloud_firestore` in flutter project
My flutter project was working perfectly fine before adding cloud_firebase to pubspec.yaml.
My firebase versions are
  firebase_core: ^2.32.0
  firebase_auth: ^4.20.0
  cloud_firestore: ^4.17.5

flutter and dart versions are
Flutter 3.22.1 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision a14f74ff3a (11 days ago) • 2024-05-22 11:08:21 -0500
Engine • revision 55eae6864b
Tools • Dart 3.4.1

Using firebase_auth for logging and signup its working fine but after add cloud_firestore and tried to run project, build takes too much time I left laptop and it takes 40 minutes and was still building.I tried to create new default test project after added firestore same thing happened and didn't build. There is no error message.Please help...
I tried flutter clean ,pod install, removing pod files vs they didn't  work

From the official documentation...
To reduce build times significantly, you can use a pre-compiled version by adding this line to the target 'Runner' do block in your Podfile:
target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  pod 'FirebaseFirestore',
    :git => 'https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git',
    :tag => 'IOS_SDK_VERSION'

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
  target 'RunnerTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end
end

